# DFT+U for RPA Ground State

Tags: vasp, reference-request, dft-u, random-phase-approximation

For RPA calculations in VASP, a [four step process](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ACFDT/RPA_calculations#General_recipe_to_calculate_ACFDT-RPA_total_energies) can be utilized where the first step is to compute the occupied orbitals at either the GGA or hybrid GGA level.

I am curious with materials that are strongly correlated, such as NiO, if this ground state should be calculated using DFT+U or not.  Are there any caveats with applying DFT+U that should be expected as well when following it up with RPA calculations?